# We hosted a website in AWS Kubernetes Service. niginx-ingress-path issue

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, amazon-eks

**We hosted a website in AWS Kubernetes Service. We are having following issue.

issue1.css not working
issue2:Redirection also not working**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myapp1-alerts-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"    
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "letsencrypt-prod"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: "/"

spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - dev-api.myapp1.solutions
    secretName: myapp1-alerts-tls
  rules:
  - host: dev-api.myapp1.solutions
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /alerts
        backend:
          serviceName: myapp1-alerts
          servicePort: 80
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Uz2QI.jpg)

Comment: What is your question exactly? Please edit your post.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/examples/rewrite/). There you will find an example below:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
  name: rewrite
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: rewrite.bar.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: http-svc
          servicePort: 80
        path: /something(/|$)(.*)
  | kubectl create -f -
```

> In this ingress definition, any characters captured by `(.*)` will be
>   assigned to the placeholder `$2`, which is then used as a parameter in
>   the rewrite-target annotation.
>
> For example, the ingress definition above will result in the following
>   rewrites:
>
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/`
> - `rewrite.bar.com/something/new` rewrites to `rewrite.bar.com/new`

Adjust your config accordingly and please let me know if that helped.